# Storage class of referenced memory

Tags: c, linux

In C, is it possible to determine the storage class of the memory a pointer points at (e.g., static, heap, stack), portably or nonportably (linux)?

I'd like to be able to do:

```
switch(storageClass(pointer)){
   case S_STACK:  puts("stack"); break;
   case S_STATIC: puts("static"); break;
   case S_HEAP: puts("heap"); break;
}
```

Comment: The C standard does not mandate a stack or heap or any other specific area. Application code should actually not rely on such implementation details.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible dynamically, you could remember this information as you declare/assign/allocate your pointers, but I can't think of a reason why you'd want to

Comment: FYI: `static` objects are typically stored in the same area as objects with external linkage. In fact the linkage is the only difference and that is mostly a matter of the symbol tables.

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick: On embedded systems with special memory management, there are very well applications. However, they normally use the addressed area to differentiate. And that should be encapsulated deep in the system-layer anyway.

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick If it's on the heap, you can realloc it, but you can't if it's elsewhere. That was my reason.

Comment: @Olaf I believe "static" is used here as "static storage duration", which includes namespace-scope objects with any linkage type.

Comment: @aschepler: You seem to be right. Anyway, an application which relies on such is imo a very bad idea.

Comment: This smells to me like an XY-problem. What do you actually want to accomplish? There might be better, standard ways you don't thnk about. Provide more context.

Comment: If you just want to memorise whether an object has to be `free`d, use a `struct` and e.g. add a `bool was_malloced;` member.

Comment: @Olaf Say I want to manipulate a string via a `char*` pointer. In some cases, I might need to grow that string, so what I would do is check whether it's a heap string and then realloc it to the needed size and if it was not, I'd malloc a copy and work with that.

Comment: Concerning "If it's on the heap, you can realloc it, but you can't if it's elsewhere."  Better to think that if the pointer is the result of `calloc()`, `malloc()`, `realloc()`, then code can use `realloc()` on that pointer.

Comment: @PSkocik: How do you know there is no external pointer to that original string. In that case you had to update every copy of the pointer to point to the new `string`. Either way, you have two different kinds of behaviour her, depending on the - say - address of that string. Sounds like a **very** bad idea to me. Better require the caller to provide large enough space or always return a copy. Not part tihs - part that, belive me,this is recipe for segfault. Even worse, `realloc` is not required to return the same address either.

Comment: @PSkocik: However, you still can use a `struct` with a `char []` _flexible array member_. Personally, I would not accept this from a co-worker or student, though.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the feedback. I'll stick to standard solutions then.

Comment: @PSkocik: Good idea. If I may, just a personal hint: A good idea when designing interfaces is the principle of least surprise. Functions (in a wider sense) which behave different on the origin/location of input behave surprisingly. This results in more debugging. Even worse, the debugger might change the behaviour compared to normal execution (Heisenberg-Effect).

Comment: If you are unsure of the source or mutability of the data presented: make a copy and work with that.